# Compactness in $\mathbb R^n $

Tags: general-topology

I am not sure if I'm missing something subtle or I'm just totally wrong.

Is the following true?\

$K\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is compact (usual topology with 2-norm) 
if and only if
$K\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is compact under a norm on $\mathbb R^n$?

I would think equivalence of norms would play a role here.

Comment: The statement is true. As you said the norms are equivalent which means that the open sets with respect to all norms are the same. Therefore by the definition of compactness (any open cover has a finite sub-cover) we have that $K$ is compact with respect to all norms.

Comment: @Yanko, I see. When you put it that way, I think it's much clearer. I was thinking of applying Heine-Borel, and that's why I'm hung up on the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. As you said this is due to the fact that in finite dimension all norms are equivalent. 
So here if $K$ is compact it just means :

$$\exists M, \forall x \in K, \|x\|_2 \leq M \text{ and } K \text{ is closed }$$

Now take any norm $N$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since all norms are equivalent then there is such that : $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \| x \|_2 \leq C N(x)$. Hence $K$ is also bounded for the norm $N$.

You can check that "closeness" still holds on $K$ with $N$.

Comment: Great! I was more sure of the closed condition being true, and was more wary of the boundedness condition. Turned out to be fine as you said!

Answer (score 0):

All norms on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are equivalent which means they yield the same topology and in particular the same compact subsets.